# Bromination of ethyl substituted benzaldehydes

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

In a material that I use to study High School Organic Chemistry, the bromination of ethyl substituted benzaldehydes is given as follows:

[image: Bromination of ethyl substituted benzaldehydes]
*Source: FIITJEE Grand Masters Package - Chemistry (JEE Preparatory Material)*

$\ce{-CHO}$ is a meta directing group, and $\ce{-C2H5}$ is an ortho, para directing group. So isn't some of the products given wrong?

For example, let's take the bromination of ortho ethyl benzaldehyde. Shouldn't the 2nd product's bromine be in a way that is in position 4 wrt $\ce{-C2H5}$ and position 3 wrt $\ce{-CHO}$?

In the meta ethyl benzaldehyde case, why is the $\ce{-CHO}$ group not affecting the position of $\ce{Br}$? Even though it is meta directing, $\ce{Br}$ doesn't seem to substitute the $\ce{H}$ in the meta position of $\ce{-CHO}$

I searched the internet for more information regarding such reactions, and could not find any helpful results for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first query is genuine and the 2nd product for the first case is wrong. It should be, as you noted as well, 5-bromo-2-ethyl-benzaldehyde.

Regarding your second query, you're wrong. Recall the general rule that:

1. when ***more than one activators*** are present on the same benzene ring, the substitution is governed by the **best activator** alone
2. when an ***activator and a deactivator*** is present on the same benzene ring, the substitution is governed by the **activator** alone
3. when ***more than one deactivators*** are present on the same benzene ring, the substitution is governed by the **weakest deactivator** alone

So, here $\ce{Br}$ will go to the o/p position of ethyl group.

---

<sup>Note that in the high school context, I've assumed we're only talking about the *major product*, because otherwise, all types of crazy products are generally formed, but in smaller ratios</sup>